# Flag email that you already replied to

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013, email-filter, rules

I would like to highlights email in my inbox that I have read and already replied to. Is there a way to use rules for this?

Thanks so much! Vince

Comment: Email icon will have a little email with an arrow on it that shows it was replied to: http://i.imgur.com/DyiXyjB.jpg

Comment: In contemporary versions replied-to is a curved arrow, in the "Icon" column which you may need to enable in the message list pane. No need for rules (in fact since you can only apply rules to emails when sent or received I don't see a way to apply a rule to an email when its replied-to, or create rules based on either status flag).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a new rule that processes your e-mail after you reply to an e-mail.

In the case below, I've created a rule to flag for followup after 7 days if the subject phrase "RE: " is in the subject.

[image]

Other options:

- You can also have a copy of your sent e-mail put in your Inbox, so that it stays visible in your Inbox to act on.
- You can also turn on View > To-Do Bar > Tasks which also list your follow up tasks on the third column. This is a nicer way to prioritize your tasks rather than using your Inbox as a to do list. Tasks allow you to sort by due date which Inbox does not let you do.